# jQuery form validation, property required if select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a webpage which renders a different form depending on the ID passed, the form is in a partial view, at present the validation is working correctly which looks like this

```
 $("#MyForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "Model.Title": "required",
        "Model.Description": "required",
        "Model.SelectedPostageOption": "required",
        "Model.PostagePrice": "required", // Required only if SelectedPostageOption is 1
    },
    messages: {
        "Model.Title": "Please enter a title for your advert",
        "Model.Description": "Please enter a description",
        "Model.SelectedPostageOption": "Please select postage option",
        "Model.PostagePrice": "Please enter postage price",
    }
});
```

As you can see I have SelectedPostageOption this gets set off a dropdown, the user can choose a value from 1 - 3, if they choose 1 I need to force them to enter a value into PostagePrice textbox, is their a property on the current jquery form validation that allows you to say "Required If" I'm currently using the following plugin jQuery Validation Plugin v1.13.1-pre

** Update **

I have amended the rule for postage price so it now look like this

```
"Model.PostagePrice": {
    required: function (element) {
      return $("#SelectedPostageOption").val() == 1;
    }
 }
```

unfortunately though when clicking the submit the message is not shown i.e Please enter postage price

Comment: I suggest that you update from "pre-release" version 1.13.1 to [the final 1.13.1](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js), which been available for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working now, I should be referencing the actual dropdown Id the below code is the final result and working as expected.

```
"Model.PostagePrice": {
   required: function (element) {
   return $("#SelectedPostageOption").val() == 1;
  }
}
```